# Dynamically hiding a section on Wordpress pages

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have a floating social bar on my website www.fashionsuggest.in

I only need this social bar on my wordpress posts and would like to to be removed from all pages.

There are only 5 or 6 pages in total. Can someone please suggest a solution to hide the floating social bar on these pages?

[Please refer the attachment to see a screenshot of the social bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9KXR.jpg)

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this CSS code.

```
.page-template-default .kiwi-floating-bar { display: none; }
.post-template-default .kiwi-floating-bar { display: block; }
```

try using !important if it doesn't reflect.

```
.page-template-default .kiwi-floating-bar { display: none !important; }
```